# Google Map is not showning properly in android

Tags: android, google-maps

My Map is shown like this

[image]

But I want to show my map as like this .![image] i have follow this tutorial [google map tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-working-with-google-maps/) .please help where I'm doing wrong ?

Api Snaphot : [image]

Comment: make sure that you are using correct map key

Comment: yes i have my own key

Comment: @PankajKumar can you tell me the main reason to happened like this ?

Comment: @kamal. Put some of your code snippet or some more description to question. It is difficult to answer otherwise..

Comment: This always happen with me when I used wrong Map key.

Comment: added <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> in manifest?

Comment: @Nilanchala , i have provide a sample code, i am using totly copy og that project

Comment: @Anu ji i have already added this is my Android menifest file

Comment: @PankajKumar , dn't know why i am facing Problem , i have made 3 apps same issue as like this, and from 3 diffrent email ids, but dnt solve my issue

Comment: please generate SHA1 key and put it your applications

Comment: i have created it already 
@YogeshTatwal

Comment: and register my application , "fingerprint;packagename" as like this @YogeshTatwal

Comment: also provide access api Google api in your google account if not than post ypur code

Comment: and also install this application on device not emulator because their is need of Google play services

Comment: I am testing this on Device,

Comment: @YogeshTatwal see snapshot of my google api console

Comment: @YogeshTatwal and in api, i have enable only Places Api

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33118/discussion-between-kamal-and-yogesh-tatwal)

Comment: Still a lot of things there,do you check your device contains correct google play service?what version of map you used? V2 or V1--each has different requirements.And last of all,android sdk contains an excellent google map code sample.Try it first before trying from other resources.

Comment: It might be because of your manifest.xml, did you add metadata to store your API Key ?

Comment: no, now i am updating my code in V2, and after that i will test it

Answer (score 1):

First of all the guide you are using is for `Google Maps API V1`. Right now there is no point in using this API version because it's deprecated and you can't receive a key as Google does not hand them out any more.

So the first suggestion would be to move your implementation to API V2. You can get an idea on how to use API V2 by reading this blog post I wrote on this matter:

[Google Maps API V2](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)